# Primary key and foreign key at the same time with doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, foreign-keys, primary-key, doctrine-orm

I have the two tables :

table **A** with **id** as primary key

table **B** with **id** as primary key and foreign key

Explanation on short:

I need to have in table **B** a primary key that also to be a foreign key that points to table **A**'s primary key.

Can anybody explain me how to map this by annotations in Doctrine 2?

Note:

I tried it By this :

```
   class A
{
    /**
     * @var bigint $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $a_id;
...
```

and **B** table:

```
class B
{
    /**
     * @var bigint $id
     * @Id 
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="A", fetch="LAZY")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $b_id;
...
```

But it gives me this error:

> Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException'
>   with message 'No identifier/primary
>   key specified for Entity 'B'. Every
>   Entity must have an identifier/primary
>   key.' in
>   /var/www/agr-reg-php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:37
>   Stack trace:

N.B: I must not have composite primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved my problem by specifying two fields in my entity class for the same column from real table. The changes are made only in class B (look at the question for class A):

```
class B
{
    /**
     * @var bigint $id
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable="false")
     */
    private $b_id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="A", fetch="LAZY")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $a;

...
```

In fact all what I have done is write two fields in my entity for the same primary key and foreign key.

Answer (score 14):

This is possible since [Doctrine 2.1](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2011/07/04/doctrine-2-1.html):

> **Identity through Foreign Entities or derived entities**: You can now use a foreign key as identifier of an entity. This translates to using @Id on a @ManyToOne or @OneToOne association. You can read up on this [feature in the tutorial](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities).

Comment: this is **already** possible. :) [Download Doctrine 2.1](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.1/download/2.1.0)

Comment: Feature in the tutorial link is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

I could solve the problem, creating a pk field with the same name to the foreign field

```
class B
{
/**
 * @var bigint $a_id
 * @Id @Column(name="a_id", type="bigint", nullable="false")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $a_id;

/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="A", fetch="LAZY")
 * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $a;
.
.
.
/**
 * @var A
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="A")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
 * })
 */
private $a;
//...
```

Comment: This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same task and experimentaly found this solution:

```
class A {  
    /**  
    * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)  
    * @GeneratedValue  
    */  
    protected $id;  

    /**  
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="a", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})  
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")  
     */  
    protected $b;  

}  

class B {  
    /**  
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="b" )  
     */  
    protected $user;  

    /**  
     * @Id  
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)  
     * @GeneratedValue  
     */  
    protected $id;  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is other temporal solution for insert:

```
    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="types")
     */
    class Type {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="type\models\Language", mappedBy="type")
     */
    private $languages;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length = 45,nullable = true)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length = 1)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length = 45)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", nullable = true)
     */
    private $datedeleted;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", nullable = true)
     */
    private $datemodificated;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateregistered;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->languages = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
        $this->status = 1;
        $this->dateregistered = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    public function id() {
            return $this->id;
    }

    public function category($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->category;
        else
            $this->category = $value;
    }

    public function name($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->name;
        else
            $this->name = $value;
    }

    public function status($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->status;
        else
            $this->status = $value;
    }

    public function datedeleted($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->datedeleted;
        else
            $this->datedeleted = $value;
    }

    public function datemodificated($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->datemodificated;
        else
            $this->datemodificated = $value;
    }

    public function dateregistered($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->dateregistered;
        else
            $this->dateregistered = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="languages")
     */
    class Language {

    /**
     * @Id 
     * @Column(name="type_id", type="integer", nullable="false")
     */
    private $language_id;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="type\models\Type",inversedBy="languages")
     * @JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length = 100, nullable = true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="string", length = 20)
     */
    private $language;

    public function language_id($value) {
        $this->language_id = $value;
    }

    public function description($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->description;
        else
            $this->description = $value;
    }

    public function language($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->language;
        else
            $this->language = $value;
    }

    public function type($value = NULL) {
        if (is_null($value))
            return $this->type;
        else
            $this->type = $value;


     }
    }

$language = new Language;
$xtype_id = $this->em->find("Type",1);
$language->language_id($xtype_id->id());
$language->type($xtype_id);
$language->description($xdescription);
$language->language($xlanguage);
$this->em->persist($this);
$this->em->flush();
```

this insert in a Class With the foreign key and primary key in language