# Doctrine 2 OneToOne from PFK of another OneToOne association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have one question. I'm using **Doctrine 2.0** and i want to know if is possible to made **OneToOne** association by using **PFK** created by another **OneToOne** assotiation as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

My code looks like this:

User class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\IdentifiedEntity
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AllianceMember", mappedBy="user")
     * var AllianceMember
     */
    protected $allianceMembership;
}
```

AllianceMember class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AllianceMember extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="allianceMembership")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AllianceRole", mappedBy="allianceMember")
     * var AllianceRole
     */
     protected $role;
```

AllianceRole class:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AllianceRole extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AllianceMember", inversedBy="role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=false)
     * @var AllianceMember
     */
    protected $allianceMember;
}
```

I'm getting this error, when I'm trying to get instance of User entity:

```
The column user_id must be mapped to a field in class App\Entity\AllianceMember since it is referenced by a join column of another class.
```

Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using mapped entities for your `@Id` has been possible since doctrine 2.1 see [Primary key and foreign key at the same time with doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383964/primary-key-and-foreign-key-at-the-same-time-with-doctrine-2)

I think you simply need to remove some of your `JoinColumn` statements. Since `@user` is already designated as your `@Id`, it isn't necessary to specify `user_id` as the JoinColumn:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AllianceMember extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="allianceMembership")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AllianceRole", mappedBy="allianceMember")
     * var AllianceRole
     */
     protected $role;
```

and

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AllianceRole extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AllianceMember", inversedBy="role")
     * @var AllianceMember
     */
    protected $allianceMember;
}
```

The id of the AllianceMember is the user_id, and the id of the AllianceRole is the id of the AllianceMember, which is user_id.

Comment: OPs code works, but with your changes it breaks. That is kinda strange.